# Logistic Regression closed form solution when using binary cross-entropy

Tags: optimization, entropy, maximum-likelihood, logistic-regression

Let's say that I want to find the stationary points of the Cross-Entropy Loss function when using a logistic regression

The 1 D logistc function is given by :
\begin{equation}\label{eq2}
\begin{split}
\sigma(wx) = \frac{1}{1+\exp{(-wx)}}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

and the cross entropy loss is given by :

\begin{equation}\label{eq3}
\begin{split}
\textbf{L}(wx) = -y \log{(\sigma(wx))} - (1-y) \log{(1-\sigma(wx))}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

When I simplify and differentiate and equal to 0, I find the following:

\begin{equation}\label{eq7}
\begin{split}
\frac{d\textbf{L}}{dw} &= (1-y)x - \frac{xe^{-wx} }{1+e^{-wx}} = 0\\
(x-xy)*(1+e^{-wx}) &=xe^{-wx} \\
(1-y)(1+e^{-wx}) &= e^{-wx}\\
1  +e^{-wx} -y- ye^{-wx} &= e^{-wx}\\
1-y - ye^{-wx}& = 0\\
1-y & = ye^{-wx}\\
\frac{(1-y)}{y} &= e^{-wx}\\
w &= - \frac{\log(\frac{(1-y)}{y})}{x}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

However, this is very weird and strongly feels very wrong:

- First x cannot be equal to 0
- Second, y cannot be equal to 0
- Third, y cannot be equal to 1

1 and 0 are the only values that y takes in a cross-entropy loss, based on my knowledge.
I am not sure where I left the right track.

I know that cross-entropy loss means there are 2 loss (one for each value of y) but I am not sure if that plays in the steps and if yes, how?
Could you please help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It seems that already the first line in your computation of the derivative is questionable. And why would you want to do this for a single data point?

Comment: Why are you saying that the first line in my computation of the derivative is questionable? and I guess you should so the sum overall points, but what would that change?

Comment: Note that  $\frac{d}{dw} \log (1 - \sigma(wx)) \ne x$.

Comment: I know. I simplified the cross-entropy function:

\begin{equation}\label{}
\begin{split}
L(wx) & = -y \log (\frac{1}{1+e^{-wx}}) - (1-y)  \log(1 - \frac{1}{1+e^{-wx}})\\
& = -y  \log(1) +y \log(1+e^{-wx}) -(1-y)  \log(e^{-wx}) +(1-y)  \log(1+e^{-wx})\\
& = y \log(1+ e^{-wx}) + (1-y)wx + \log(1+e^{-wx})-y \log(1+e^{-wx})\\
& = (1-y)\,wx +  \log(1+e^{-wx})
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Comment: @HansEngler please if you know how to find the solution, can you please show? I spent more than 2 days trying to work it work.

Comment: Here is a link to a paper with a derivation. The notation is somewhat different, and cross entropy is called the log likelihood (it's the same thing).   http://www.haija.org/derivation_logistic_regression.pdf

Comment: Thanks, @HansEngler. In the paper they said:"Finally, it is important to note that it is not possible to set ∇wl(w) = 0 and solve for w, as the $\sigma$ is a non-linear function." do you know why?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115212/discussion-between-hans-engler-and-lalaland).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$
\def\l{\lambda}\def\s{\sigma}
\def\o{{\tt1}}\def\p{\partial}
\def\L{\left}\def\R{\right}
\def\LR#1{\L(#1\R)}
\def\BR#1{\Big(#1\Big)}
\def\trace#1{\operatorname{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
$The derivative of the logistic function is [well-known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function#Derivative)
$$\eqalign{
z &= wx \\
\s(z) &= \LR{\o+e^{-z}}^{-1} \\
d\s &= \LR{\s-\s^2}dz \;=\; \LR{\s-\s^2}x\,dw \\
}$$
Calculate the differential of the loss function wrt $\s$ then change the independent variable to $w$ before recovering the gradient.
$$\eqalign{
\l &= -(\o-y):\log(\o-\s) - y:\log(\s) \\
d\l &=  -(\o-y):d\log(\o-\s) - y:d\log(\s) \\
 &=  -(\o-y):\fracLR{d\LR{\o-\s}}{\o-\s} - y:\fracLR{d\s}{\s} \\
 &=  \LR{\frac{\o-y}{\o-\s} - \frac{y}{\s}}:d\s \\
 &=  \fracLR{\s-y}{\s-\s^2}:\BR{\LR{\s-\s^2}x\;dw} \\
 &=  \BR{\LR{\s-y}x}:dw \\
\grad{\l}{w} &= {\LR{\s-y}x} \\
}$$
This gradient is equal to zero if $\;x=0\;$ or if
$$y=\s=\LR{\o+e^{-wx}}^{-1} \qiq xw = \log\fracLR{y}{\o-y}$$

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I just want to note that it is important to keep in mind that in this case y can be either equal to 0 or 1.  Therefore when analyzing the behavior of the function we need to analyze both cases separately.